# Are there any known uncountable transfinite increasing sequences of real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

The real numbers are uncountable, so assuming the axiom of choice there is at least transfinite sequence of real numbers $r_0, r_1, r_2, ..., r_\omega, r_{\omega + 1}, ..., $ up to (and possibly including) $r_{\omega_1}$ that contains an uncountable number of terms. However, it's not guaranteed that $r_0 < r_1 < ..., r_\omega < ...$

Is there a known transfinite sequence of real numbers that is monotonically increasing and which contains uncountably many real numbers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $r_{\alpha} < r_{\alpha + 1}$, then there exists a rational number between the two numbers. Hence the sequence can be corresponded with a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, and so must be countable.

Comment: That's a beautiful observation. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @templatetypedef Thanks. It's a useful fact to know; it's also the basic observation leading to a proof that a monotone function can only have countably many discontinuities on $\mathbb{R}$.